# How is the LCDC (LCD Control) register manipulated on the Gameboy?

Tags: game-boy

I don't see it listed anywhere in the 0000-ffff address space. Is it controled by the CPU? Or something else entirely?

Comment: Would it be possible to link the source you're reffering to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's controlled by the programmer, not the CPU. The LCDC is located at memory address `&FF40` and can be read from/written to just like any other piece of memory. This memory location is one byte long and each bit represents a specific hardware feature related to the screen. In the list below, bit 7 is the "leftmost" bit, bit 0 is the "rightmost."

- Bit 7: If this equals 1, the screen is on. If it's 0, the screen is off.
- Bit 6: If this equals 1, the "window" gets its tile data from addresses `&9C00-&9FFF`. If this equals 0, the "window" gets its tile data from addresses `&9800-&9BFF`.
- Bit 5: Turns the "window" on or off. The window is a separate layer from the background and sprites, which uses its own tilemap. (You have two choices for where that tilemap can be stored, Bit 6 decides which one is active.)
- Bit 4: The Game Boy will pull its sprite graphics data from memory area `&8000-&8FFF` if this bit equals 1. If 0, the sprite graphics come from `&8800-&97FF`.
- Bit 3: The Game Boy will pull background graphics from memory area `&9C00-&9FFF` if this bit equals 1. If this bit equals 0, they come from `&9800-&9BFF` instead.
- Bit 2: If this bit equals 1, sprites are 8x16 pixels in size. If 0, they are 8x8.
- Bit 1: Sprites are only visible if this bit equals 1.
- Bit 0: The background is only visible if this bit equals 1. (This is only true for the original Game Boy - on the Game Boy Color, the background is always visible.)

There are a few ways to write to this register, I'll quickly list some.

```
LD HL,&FF40
SET 7,(HL)   ;turn on the screen. This method can only alter one setting at a time,
             ;but it won't affect any other settings.
```

```
LD A,%11100111
LD (&FF40),A
;turn on screen, window tiles come from &9C00+, window on,
;sprites from &8800, background from &9800, 8x16 sprites, sprites on, background on

;This method quickly changes a bunch of settings at once, but any old settings 
;are replaced with the new ones.
```

Just as a warning: If you clear bit 7 of LCDC outside of VBlank, you run the risk of damaging the screen. Emulators aren't affected by this of course, but a real Game Boy is. If you're going to shut off the screen during the game (which you will need to do to load graphics) you need to call a procedure that waits for VBlank first, then as soon as you return clear bit 7 of LCDC.

There's more explained [in the *Pan Docs*](https://gbdev.io/pandocs/LCDC.html).

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Why do you think will the screen be damaged?

Comment: The PanDocs says it will happen. I haven't tested it personally but I'd rather not find out. Supposedly Nintendo knew this was a problem and wouldn't publish a game that didn't wait for vBlank to clear bit 7 of &FF40.

Answer (score 3):

The [LCD control block](https://gbdev.gg8.se/wiki/articles/Video_Display) is located at FF40h and the [LCDC](https://gbdev.gg8.se/wiki/articles/LCDC) is the first thereof, see as well the [Pandocs](http://bgb.bircd.org/pandocs.htm#videodisplay).